# How to ensure Borderless WPF Application runs in filled mode in Windows 8?

Tags: wpf, windows-8

I am creating a borderless WPF Application. How can I ensure it runs in all the three visual states i.e. Full screen mode, Filled mode & Snapped mode?

Comment: Are you refering to the metro(yes i continue to call it metro!) screen modes? Because you can't develop a WPF Metro application. Your WPF application will ONLY run on the desktop and only on WOA devices. And there you have fullscreen, screensnap, maximized, windowed etc. screen modes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am referring to Metro screen modes and my intention is to run my application on desktop. Where can I find the above mentioned screen modes? (fullscreen, screensnap, maximized, windowed). Is it specific to .NET 4? Currently I am using .NET 3.5

Comment: honestly, i don't know were you could find them. They are not bound to be WPF specific they are windows specific almost since windows 95. But you are using WPF, so thanks to the automatic layouting a lot of work is already done for you. Out of my head the important modes are: Normal(any size, any position), Minimized, Maximized, Fullscreen(which is not actually a mode, its the same as maximized without a border) And aero snap, which is badly handled in wpf imho.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at this library

MahApps.Metro

It has lot of windows 8 metro style controls, and borderless window.

http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

N Route also have a full sample application with borderless windows

http://nroute.codeplex.com/